# php artisan tinker (null) hasmany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Region.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Region extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['region'];

    public function passport()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\passport');
    }
}
```

passport.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class passport extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'passport';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'no_pass', 'negara', 'city', 'image', 'regions_id'];

    public function region()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\region');
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please clarify more?

Comment: Could be that `App\region` does not exist because your model is called `Region`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model should be like this

```
public function passports()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\passport','regions_id','id');
}
```

Execute this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then execute your artisan command

```
$region = \App\Region::find(1);
$region->passports;
```

Comment: it should be `regions_id` or `region_id`. Your table name `passport` or `passports`. Your model mane `Passport` or `passport`. And share your database table

Comment: my table passport(regions_id) regions(region) my model name passport.php and Region.php

Comment: is it work `$region = \App\Region::find(1);` @Fernanda